fopen returns null but errno = 0: success
I'm trying to write to a text file in C, which is in the same directory as main, but fopen keeps returning NULL. Most of the replies on here say to print the value of errno, but errno is 0 which is a success. I'm not sure how to fix this.
This is what I have.
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void write_To_File(double num) {
    FILE *fptr = fopen("data.txt", "w"); // open filename in write mode
    if (fptr == NULL) { 
        fprintf(stderr, "open errno = %d: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        return;
    } 
    fprintf(fptr, "%lf\n", num);
    fclose(fptr);
    return;
}

int main(void) {
    double num = 3.5;
    write_To_File(num);
}

This is the program's output:
open errno = 0: Success


please provide a complete (eg compilable and runnable) minimal reproduction.

The program has undefined behavior since you supply a FILE* where a char* is expected in the fprintf. Do you still get the same problem if you remove the first %s and  fptr  in the argument list to fprintf?

yes i get the same problem when i remove the first %s and fptr in the argument list to fprintf.

@malaika Ok, but you will likely be asked again and again about it until you fix it in your question so I fixed that.

The C standard specification for fopen() does not require it to set errno on error.  The POSIX specification for fopen() does require errno to be set, but notes it is an extension over what the C standard requires.

On a side note: when using fprintf(stderr, "...\n") to log errno, consider using perror() instead, eg: perror("open failed"); It will write to stderr and print out the errno error message after the specified string.

so how do I figure out why fopen is returning NULL and how do I fix it?

What operating system are you using? what version? What compiler are you using? What version? What command line options are you passing to the compiler or how is your compiler configured? "How" are you executing the program - in a command line or in some program or in what environment? Are you compiling any other files? "Where" -   in the sense in which current working directory - are you executing the program? Do you have file creation rights in that directory? Anything else that could  point as to how or where is your verion of fopen() function implemented that you are using?

@gregspears Obviously you have to run the program in such a way that opening the file gets an error. The question is about reporting the reason why fopen() fails.

"so how do I figure out why fopen is returning NULL and how do I fix it?" -- with the OS not offering help, you'll just need to the possibilities until you find the error. Likely issues include: (i) you don't have permission to write in the program's working directory; and (ii) there is already a file data.txt in the working directory, and you do not have sufficient permissions to modify it; and (iii) (on Windows) some other file has the file open.  Note well that the working directory is determined by how you launch the program, not by where the executable is or where the source is.

If this is Windows, you should also call GetLastError(). I think that Windows will usually set errno, but not always. GetLastError() should help.

Your program now is correct.  So what do you want we to do?  You have changed the source so many times that finally it is correct.  We cannot reproduce your problem.  Don't change the source question to correct the error, the question will not be valid anymore.

There could be multiple reasons for fopen to fail and return NULL. On POSIX compliant systems, errno is set to help the caller determine the reason for failure and act accordingly. The value of errno will be set either by malloc() in case of a memory allocation issue, open() if the file could not be opened by the system (invalid path, read only file system, insufficient rights...) or by fopen itself for other reasons (out of FILE handles).
Your approach using errno and strerror is fine. You should probably add the name of the file in the error message for the user to have a full informative error message:
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int write_To_File(double num) {
    FILE *fptr = fopen("data.txt", "w"); // open filename in write mode
    if (fptr == NULL) { 
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s for writing: %s (errno = %d)\n",
                "data.txt", strerror(errno), errno);
        return -1;
    } 
    fprintf(fptr, "%f\n", num);
    fclose(fptr);
    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    double num = 3.5;
    write_To_File(num);
    return 0;
}

On other systems, the behavior will depend on quality of implementation.  Not setting errno is sloppy, yet not incorrect, but setting errno to 0 would be a violation of §7.5 ¶3 of the ISO C11 standard. The most likely explanation is fopen did not set errno and errno still has its initial value of 0.
The C Standard does not mandate fopen to set errno in case of failure. This is unfortunate and there is no standard way to investigate the reason for failure. There might be a system specific API to retrieve more information (such as GetLastError() on Microsoft Windows) or a system specific API to try and open a file with an error code in case of failure.

Probably the fopen() is not setting errno to 0; it may already be set to 0 before the call.

@malaika: you can accept this answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.
